# Django Regex Sub

Tags: regex, django, django-views

I wish to bold the pattern that matches the result. So, this is my code:

```
re.sub(r'[[:<:]]'+tagdef.content+'[[:>:]]', r'\1<b>'+tagdef.content+'</b>\2', qitem['value'])
```

However it seems not to be working. This was previously taught by another guy in stackoverflow community. Not sure if I got it right.

Basically tagdef.content is a regex expression (e.g. increas.*), and qitem['value'] is a string that I need to check for its existence.

Expected Scenario if I have..

```
tagdef.content = "increas.*"
qitem['value'] = "the rate of increase in the market was increased by 100%"
```

Result must be:

```
"the rate of <b>increase</b> in the market was <b>increased</b> by 100%"
```

Comment: hi, sorry the regex part is only this part. do i miss something?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you might work this snippet - maybe input and expected output. What isn't working, are you getting an error (which you could post) or does the code behave unexpectedly?

Comment: Okay, I have editted and showed more info

Comment: What happens to the code when you run it now, as it is asked?